# How to refer to variable-length structures

Tags: c, struct

The below code refuses to compile in SDCC, because of my use of flexible array members (the `"This line"`s).

```
/** header of string list */
typedef struct {
    int nCount;
    int nMemUsed;
    int nMemAvail;
} STRLIST_HEADER;

/** string list entry data type */
typedef struct {
    int nLen;
    char str[];                    // This line
} STRLIST_ENTRY;

/** string list data type */
typedef struct {
    STRLIST_HEADER header;
    STRLIST_ENTRY entry[];         // This line
} STRLIST;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

However, the data I have to access is already set up this way (I'm accessing existing memory via pointers, not smashing the stack), and using a struct pointer makes for very clean code.  Unfortunately SDCC does not like this.  What is an alternative way I could refer to the memory structure in my code that will compile cleanly?

Comment: Per the standard, structures with flexible array members must not be members of structures or elements of an array. So `STRLIST` is not valid.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know.  What would be the best way to rewrite this code so that it is according to standard?

Comment: Good question. That you marked the `char str[];` line makes me suspect SDCC doesn't like flexible array members at all? In that case, the only options I see is to set a fixed size for the arrays, or use pointers (and give up locality). If it accepts flexible array members, but not recursively, you could cheat and use `unsigned entry[];` in `STRLIST`. Also not entirely satisfactory, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to give the array member a size:

```
typedef struct {
    int nLen;
    char str[1];
} STRLIST_ENTRY;
```

That keeps the compiler happy.

**Edit**: Can you use the `--std-c99` or `--std-sdcc99` switches to make SDCC understand your original code?

Comment: I see...  One issue.  I would like `sizeof(STRLIST_ENTRY)` to return the size of the struct without the variable member.  (The code is already written for a different compiler that allows this!)  Is there a version of this (`str[0]` maybe?) that would do this?  Or should I just modify the code with `sizeof(...) - 1` across the board?

Comment: @gh403: Maybe you can persuade SDCC to understand your original code - see my edited answer.

Comment: No :(.  I get `warning 186: invalid use of structure with flexible array member` followed by `error 200: field 'entry' has incomplete type`, both referring to the second `// This line`.

Comment: @gh403: As Daniel Fischer points out, you can't put these things in an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
    int nLen;
    char *str;                    
} STRLIST_ENTRY;
```

I would do it this way and malloc the array when ready to use it. Is there any particular reason you are using all caps to define a struct name? Usually these are lowercase in most coding standards.

Comment: I can't `malloc` the array.  The data is already in place in memory.